# Mercurial, push just to one developer

Tags: mercurial, push

I'm trying to find out Mercurial advantages and i've read something about commiting between developers without influence on main branch.

I know i have to commit to my local repo, and then what? I don't like to push it to server (then everyone will see it right?), but just to one concrete user. I'd like him to fix something for me and send me back his changeset. Then later I'll push everything to server.

How can i do that? How should i do that in mercurial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `hg serve` on your system.  It will print something like:

```
listening at http://yoursystem.someplace.com:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
```

Assuming the other developer also has a clone of the server project, he can run:

```
hg pull http://yoursystem.someplace.com:8000
```

to get your updates.

Later you can reverse the process to get his changes back to you.

Answer (score 4):

Hg serve is the easiest way, but if firewalls prevent you from doing that you can create a bundle and send it by email:

```
hg bundle thebundlefiletocreate.bundle http://URL/of/your/central/repo
```

then you can email the resulting `thebundlefiletocreate.bundle` file to the person.  They can apply it with:

```
hg unbundle `thebundlefiletocreate.bundle`
```

This is a pretty clumsy way to work though.  Using hg serve back and forth (as Mark suggested) is better if possible.  Ideally you create a repo you can both read/write on a shared server or drive and both push/pull to it.

Comment: Thought I'd mention that you can also `pull` from a bundle file, allowing you to pull a single branch, for example, and you can also `clone`. They're very useful.